# Poco based binary cannot find library during runtime

Tags: linux, runtime, poco, dynamic-linking, poco-libraries

I have written a small HTTPServer application using Poco and I get the following error during runtime:

> factoryProject> ./httpServer  ./httpServer: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libPocoNet.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

My libraries successfully linked during compilation because they were located in a specific directory that I pointed to in my make file using a `-L/some/path`.

I have read up on the ldconfig command and it stated that it usually looks for libraries in `/usr/lib`, but I do not have admin privee to add the Poco libraries into that directory.

How do I point to that a custom library directory so that ld will load it during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into a few possible solutions with the most popular being to [add a config file for ldconfig to pickup](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/), but this solution seems complicated and I do not want to add a config file to this common server.

The solution that was the simplest for me was to update the following environment variable:

> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

The [LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) can list directories where libraries are searched for first during runtime and after `setenv` command I have a working HTTP server!

Comment: You're better off also passing in: `-Wl,-rpath,/some/path` to the link line of the program so it looks in that location when running rather than relying on the environment variable. the `-L` option does link time, the `-Wl,-rpath` embeds it into the binary for run-time

Comment: @Petesh Great suggestion. I actually prefer this since it brings the definition of the path into the makefile. After reading the following [link](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/rpath/) I updated my LDFLAGS to the following: `LDFLAGS=-lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoFoundation -lPocoXML -Wl,-rpath=$(LIB_DIR),--enable-new-dtags`